# execlp() output cannot be redirected to stdout with pipe

Tags: c++, linux, exec, fork, parent-child

I have the following program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int p[2];
  int code;
  pid_t pid;
  if(-1==(pipe(p)))
  {
    cout<<"Pipe error!"<<endl;
    return 1;
  }
  if(-1==(pid=fork()))
  {
    cout<<"Fork error!"<<endl;
    return 1;
  }
  if(pid==0)
  {
     dup2(p[1],1);//duplicates stdout?
     close(p[0]);//closes reading end
     execlp("grep","grep","/bin/bash","/etc/passwd",NULL);
     return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    cout<<"works so far"<<endl;
    wait(&code);
    cout<<"Doesn't get here"<<endl;
    //how do i read from the pipe to print on the screen what execlp wanted to ?
  }
return 1;
}
```

I want to redirect the execlp output in the pipe so that the parent can read it and print it itself.
I understand that execlp overwrites the child process and it prints to stdout itself, but i need the parent to do that.

From what i understand so far, when i do dup2(p[1],1) it duplicates the stdout and it closes it too. So that execlp would write to the lowest value descriptor (that being my pipe since it closed and copied stdout). Where am i wrong ?

p.s. I compile with g++

Comment: Note: `wait(code)` isn't valid. You're passing the *value* of an indeterminate `int` variable rather than the *address* of an `int` variable, and thus your compiler won't even compile this. If it does, get a new compiler.

Comment: My mistake, it was `wait(&code);`

Comment: And that fixed, I have no problem reaching, and printing "Doesn't get here", so I'm not sure what your issue is. Your not even waiting on the parent-process end of that pipe, just waiting for the child process to terminate.

Comment: It just hangs for me. Also could you explain further what you mean by waiting on the parent-process end of the pipe ?

Comment: I added further info in the code

Comment: I mean, your parent process has the read-end (actually both ends, but you care about the read-end) of the pipe, and the child is being forked, then execlp-ing. The parent should be closing the write-side of the pipe, then reading using `read()` on the read-end until zero or error is returned.

Comment: Oh, i understand, but my problem is that the program loops(i guess, or just hangs) before `wait()` I think somewhere in the child

Comment: @WhozCraig Have you used g++ for compiling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by dup-ing `stdout` towards a file (descriptor), then in the parent process i open and read `execlp`'s output from it.